# How to get the path of a fish script within itself

Tags: shell, fish

In bash, we can get the path of a script with `$0`. It seems that we can do that in a fish script by `$_` according to the official document.

How ever, if I try to write a fish script like this, and run it, it will print just a newline.

```
#!/usr/bin/fish
echo $_
```

While in a reactive fish, `echo $_` will give `echo` literately and `<command> $_` will pass "command" literately as `<command>`'s argument.

I am confused about the strange behavior of `$_`, and what it is used for.

Comment: Could you point me to the section in the docs that lead you to believe `$_` would contain the current filename? The only place where it's mentioned in the current docs is in the "Programmable Title" section, and it says explicitly it's "the name of the job to be put into the foreground".

Comment: 1st, I think it needs more examples to clarify what exactly the `Programmable title` section want to say. 2nd, since a function's behavior is similar to a fish script. For example, both accept parameters and receive parameters in a `$argv[$i]` way. It temps me to think that since `$_` can give the containing function's name, `$_` may also give the script's name when` $_` is in top level. 3rd, Since bash use `$0` to represent the script itself, it temps me to think fish uses a similar macro to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_` is a bit confusing, but it's not the "path to the fish script", it's the name of the current foreground job.

To get the path to the script, use `status --current-filename` (which will be "standard input" if launched interactively).

Comment: It's actually capitalized: "Standard input". Wonder if it's too late to change it to all lowercase as the capitalization is weird since it isn't a sentence.